# Flutter : Show ListView.builder items where Id is element in List<String>

Tags: flutter, dart

I have `final favoriteIds = watch(FavoriteIds.provider);` that contains list of string of favorited item's Id. Then, I want to create a ListView.builder that show the favorited item. All of Id of favorited items stored in favoriteIds variable. So, how can I implement the ListView.builder with just favorited item? This is my code:

```
widget(
  child: favoriteIds.contains(doa.id.toString())
      ? Padding(
          padding:
              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
          child: Card(
            elevation: 0,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            ),
            child: Container(
              // margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              //     vertical: 8),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: Style().gradasi2,
                  borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.circular(20)),
              child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(doa.judul!,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: "Poppins",
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 16,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder:
                                (BuildContext context) =>
                                    DetailDoa(doa: doa)));
                  },
                  trailing: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  )),
            ),
          ),
        )
      : // if Id is not element of favoriteIds
      Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32),
          child: Text(
            "Yuk cari doa dan masukkan ke dalam daftar doa favoritmu.",
            style: Style().body,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          )),
),
```

I think there is some logic error in my code. Please help me to solve this problem.
Thank you :)

Comment: ```favoriteIds``` is this list of all Ids or only the favourated itemIds?

Comment: @MaheshJamdade only favorited item ids

Comment: And then what is this condition for in 
```favoriteIds.contains(doa.id.toString())```?

Comment: @MaheshJamdade I'm not sure, but I think that condition is for show item whose id is listed in favoriteids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can distinguish between Item and show a widget accordingly while building the item.

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: favoriteIds.length,,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (favoriteIds.contains(doa.id.toString())) {
      return YourFavourateWidget();
    } else {
      return YourNonFavourateWidget();
    }
}),
```

Comment: I tried this but only 1 item that shown in ListTile :( even there are 3 Ids in favoriteIds

Comment: https://replit.com/join/pspisptr-nabilrei Here is my full code

Comment: owh solved. just change itemCount into length of all data, not just length of favoriteIds. Thank you :)

Comment: glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
  return ListTile(
     item: favoriteIds[index],
  );
 },
  itemCount: favoriteIds.length,
),
```

Make sure `favoriteIds` is a list type

Comment: there is an error if I insert `item` parameter into ListTile : `The named parameter 'item' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'item'.`